# How to remove empty XML child tags from an XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am looking to remove empty xml tags which are under a particular tag.

For Example, I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<apiRequest>
   <policyTransaction>
     <addDriver>
       <driverName>xyz</driverName>
       <IsCoInsured/>
       <OnlyInsuredWithThisPolicy/>
     </addDriver>
     <retrieveDrivers/>
     <validateDrivers/>
   </policTransaction>
</apirequest>
```

I want this to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
    <apiRequest>
       <policyTransaction>
         <addDriver>
           <driverName>xyz</driverName>
         </addDriver>
         <retrieveDrivers/>
         <validateDrivers/>
       </policTransaction>
    </apirequest>
```

I am using the code below to do this

```
 var doc= XDocument.Parse(requestString);

 var emptyElements = from descendant in doc.Descendants()
                     where descendant.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(descendant.Value)
                     select descendant;
 emptyElements.Remove();
```

But the elements after the adddriver also get eliminated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<apiRequest>
   <policyTransaction>
     <addDriver>
       <driverName>xyz</driverName>                                        
     </addDriver>
   </policTransaction>
</apirequest>
```

Which I don't want to happen. How could I check only for child elements to be removed if they are empty? I want the elements retrieveDrivers and validateDrivers to be there.

The above is obtained by a request, so once this XML is sent I get the response back with the elements for those two tags filled.

Comment: "i want the elements retrieveDrivers and validateDrivers to be there." - Why? They're empty elements. You said you wanted empty elements to be removed. I suspect you haven't thought through your condition clearly enough.

Comment: As i said this is the  request xml sent as a string to the server. We get response with those values having elements under them like the add driver has  driverName element under it.

Comment: Do you only want to remove empty tags in the addDriver section, or in the policyTransaction section but leave retrieveDrivers and validateDrivers?

Comment: I want to remove tags under the addDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to only remove empty elements from a specific element, not the document in general, so instead of

```
doc.Decendants()
```

use

```
doc.Descendants("addDriver").Elements() // all sub elements of elements called addDriver
```

This is the most simple solution. This doesnt remove elements that had only empty elements.

Be careful though, if there are namespaces declared, you have to use the correct XName instead of plain string. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

### Edit

---

Here is a more generic approach
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class Program
    {

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?>
<apiRequest>
   <policyTransaction>
     <addDriver>
       <driverName>xyz</driverName>
       <IsCoInsured/>
       <OnlyInsuredWithThisPolicy/>
     </addDriver>
     <retrieveDrivers/>
     <validateDrivers/>
   </policyTransaction>
</apiRequest>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        doc.Root.RemoveEmptyChildren("addDriver");

        Console.WriteLine(doc);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class XElementExtension
{
    public static void RemoveEmptyChildren(this XElement element, XName name = null, bool recursive = false)
    {
        var children = name != null ? element.Descendants(name) : element.Descendants();
        foreach (var child in children.SelectMany(child => child.Elements()).ToArray())
        {
            if (child.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(child.Value))
                child.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The code you asked me to use is working fine but can't it be generic because what if I am using some other xml in the future and it has the requirement the same way like this. Is there no way to check for the child Elements and then remove it?

Comment: Yeah sure, there is.
I will rewrite this, give me a few seconds.

Comment: This is the working the same way as the above code. I don't want to hardcode anything. It should search for the child elements and eliminate those.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the serializer to skip that value if it has a null while using xmlWriter in c#. so that it won't generate that tag. That would be simple I guess rather doing all this stuff?

Comment: Is there a way I could harcode saying exclude these tags without removing them. When using the above code rather I say to remove elements after addDriver. Can't I say just exclude these so that what ever xml I pass I could maintain a list of elements that shouldnt be excluded.

Comment: Yeah you can, its time for you to show some effort by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine If I use it in this way.

```
var requestString = XmlSerializer.Serialize(request);

            var requestStringWithoutNullElements = XDocument.Parse(requestString);

            var emptyElements = from descendant in requestStringWithoutNullElements.Descendants()
                                where descendant.IsEmpty && descendant.Name != "retrieveDrivers" && descendant.Name != "validateDrivers"
                                select descendant;
            emptyElements.Remove();
```